# Cassandra filter based on secondary index

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, cassandra

We have been using Cassandra for awhile now and we are trying to get a really optimized table going that will be able to quickly query and filter on about 100k rows.

Our model looks something like this:

```
class FailedCDR(Model):  
    uuid = columns.UUID(partition_key=True, primary_key=True)
    num_attempts = columns.Integer(index=True)
    datetime = columns.Integer()
```

If I describe the table it clearly shows that `num_attempts` is index.

```
CREATE TABLE cdrs.failed_cdrs (
    uuid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    datetime int,
    num_attempts int
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX index_failed_cdrs_num_attempts ON cdrs.failed_cdrs (num_attempts);
```

We want to be able to run a filter similar to this:

```
failed = FailedCDR.filter(num_attempts__lte=9)
```

But this happens:

```
QueryException: Where clauses require either a "=" or "IN" comparison with either a primary key or indexed field
```

How can we accomplish a similar task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a range query in CQL, you need the field to be a clustering column.

So you'll want the num_attempts field to be a clustering column.

Also if you want to do a single query, you need all the rows you want to query in the same partition (or a small number of partitions that you can access using an IN clause).  Since you only have 100K rows, that is small enough to fit in one partition.

So you could define your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.failed_cdrs (
    partition int,
    num_attempts int,
    uuid uuid,
    datetime int,
    PRIMARY KEY (partition, num_attempts, uuid));
```

You would insert your data with a constant for the partition key, such as 1.

```
INSERT INTO failed_cdrs (uuid, datetime, num_attempts, partition)
    VALUES ( now(), 123, 5, 1);
```

Then you can do range queries like this:

```
SELECT * from failed_cdrs where partition=1 and num_attempts >=8;
```

The drawback to this method is that to change the value of num_attempts, you need to delete the old row and insert a new row since you are not allowed to update key fields.  You could do the delete and insert for that in a batch statement.

A better option that will become available in Cassandra 3.0 is to make a materialized view that has num_attempts as a clustering column, in which case Cassandra would take care of the delete and insert for you when you updated num_attempts in the base table.  The 3.0 release is currently in beta testing.